# Having trouble using Barba.js and separate JS files

Tags: javascript, wordpress, barbajs

I've setup Barba.js on my Wordpress website. It seems to be working. the only thing is that when I transition to other pages, my other JS files don't load until a hard refresh.

I think to solve this, I have to use `namespace` and `BeforeEnter` and re-run my separate JS file within that

The only problem is I don't know how to do that. I've looked all over the net.

I've tried this (which I know is not right, but maybe on the right track?)

```
let script = document.createElement('script');
script.src="/flickity.init.js";   
next.container.appendChild(script);
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Was actually a pretty simple fix.

I just wrapped my other JS files code in a const `runScripts = function () {}` then called the function runScripts() inside a view in my custom Barba script  with `beforeEnter({ next }) {}` and a relevant name space.